# Image is not stretched on another monitor

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have this part of HTML file

```
<div id="header">
...
</div>
```

and this part of CSS file

```
#header {
  background: url("img.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

The size of img.png is 1290 x 150 pixels. Everything was OK, but after I opened the web in sister's laptop the image is not stretched over all monitor (horizontally). There is about 50 pixels gap from the right.
Is there some general solution, so that the web will display same on all monitors?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on different screen resolutions useed by different monitors/devices.

You could let the image stretch to the size of the monitor if you use an image tag to display the image, and specify its `width` and `height` properties to be 100%, but that will result in a stretched image depending of the device used...

I suggest you to look for some tutorials about centering images while occupying all the avaiable space without blank space, and retaining image proportions at the same time.

Comment: I realized I can't use `img` tag because image is background behind some text, logos etc.

Answer (score 1):

your css code will **not** strech your background immage, it will only not repeat. as far as I know CSS wont even do that (streching an  is possibe )

Comment: But there should be some way to display the image on all monitors the same or not?

Comment: center the imge and fade it out on the sides to the BG color, or use an img elemnt that is streched (but I would never do the last one)

Comment: There is CSS attribute for fading the image out on the sides or should I do it in graphics editor? Why wouldn't you never do it with img element?

Comment: becouse that gives me a usless element in my markup, wich you should avoid at all times. the image should be done in the graphics editor

Comment: Can I test the result on some webservice to be sure that it is OK for all monitors? I don't have the possibility to view the pages on so many monitors that exist.